# error in displaying message in chat app in android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an app in android studio in which I want to add group chat functionality but the code I am using to display the message is showing error. the error is

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
>               at com.e.whatsapp.GroupChatActivity.onStart(GroupChatActivity.java:69)

```
private DatabaseReference UsersRef, GroupNameRef, GroupMessageKeyRef;

 protected void onStart() {

        super.onStart();
        GroupNameRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    DisplayMessages(dataSnapshot);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    DisplayMessages(dataSnapshot);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, sir I don't know How I forgot that. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

None of the [DatabaseReferences](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) has been initialized yet

```
private DatabaseReference UsersRef, GroupNameRef, GroupMessageKeyRef;
```

You should initialize them in your `onCreate()` method as

```
UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
GroupNameRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
GroupMessageKeyRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

**Note**

When you use `GroupNameRef.addChildEventListener...` first define the child where your reference is pointing at to listen to those values

```
GroupNameRef.child("groups").addChildEventListener...
```

or initialize it in your `onCreate()` as

```
GroupNameRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("groups");
```